# Problem with a Digital Piano

Tags: maintenance, sound, digital-piano

So, I have a digital piano, a Casio CDP 130 that I bought at the start of the year. It has been working perfectly until yesterday a friend of mine was playing it and noticed that when the seventh B of the piano is pressed, all the keys near it lose all sensitivity. They sound louder even with the softest touch.

I don't use that part of the piano that often but it really bothers me because if I press that note and then another one near that one it sound really loud and breaks the harmony.

As I have said, it started happening recently. For details, I have a cat and she oftenly sits on top of the piano, but only when the piano is in its cover. I also clear it with napkins before and after playing. But even though I pressume that some of my cat's hair has gone into the piano and is causing this problem. I don't have a lot of knowledge on digital piano so I don't want to open it and break it completely, so if anyone knows how to resolve this problem it would very much appreciated.

Edit: As someone has asked in the comments, yes, the problems goes away as soon as I stop pressing the 7B key.

Edit2: So, I was about to open the piano in order to see if there was dust or something else in the key, but before I opened it I played the key once again to be sure it was that one, and suddenly the problem isn't there anymore. No matter if the key is pressed or not, the keys retain their sensitivity. So no more problem. I will be having an eye on that key even though in case something happens. Thanks to everyone who answered me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is the piano still under warranty?

Comment: Sure sounds like dirt is causing one of the under-layers of the keys to get dragged around when you play the 7B key.  Does this problem go away as soon as you release that key?

Comment: Yes it goes away as soon as I release it. Added it now on the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure your cat has done no more than SIT on the keyboard, return it under warranty.  You must get at least a year?

If you must try to fix this yourself, and have the right sort of skills, dismantle down to the key contacts and associated circuit board.  My instinct tells me we're looking for an electrical problem here rather than a simple 'bit of dirt'.  But have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a vacuum with a hose to get rid of any dust fallen between the keys? I had an issue with my Yamaha where one went much louder than the others. A good vacuum cured it a lot and it went away completely with more use.